# Is there a modern equivalent for windscreen piece 6152?

Tags: piece-information

For a creation I'm building, I am using a white windscreen piece (part ID 6152).

[image]

Looks like this piece was last produced in the late 1990's. Is there a modern equivalent that preserves this general shape?

Comment: Maybe a bit later than the late 90-s, I have lots of these in early 2000-s sets...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The windscreen you mentioned has been retired, however you can still get it on BrickLink. It is available inexpensively in several colors: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6152

If you want to use a modern version, this wedge is pretty close in shape and is available in current sets: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6153b

As a reference, here are all the LEGO windscreens LEGO ever made. You can browse them by year released and sets they appear in: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=115

And here are all the wedge elements LEGO ever made. They tend to use these more often these days, most likely because of the stronger/thicker walls: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=42

Comment: Great, thanks! Unfortunately 6153b won't cut it here. I'm happy to settle for the windscreen, even if it means using a old-style part.

Comment: No shame in using older/retired LEGO elements. There are many great parts that have been retired, but they can still add nice details and make your creation even more unique. :)